# OSI Model Layer

Tags: networking, model, layer, osi

If a server is indicating that it is accepting connections, via fping (IP address indicating "is alive") is this layer 7 Application in the OSI Model or is this a layer 3 Network?

At What layer in the OSI Model is this?

kind of confused tried Wiki need further breakdown please thanks in advance.

Comment: The OSI model is just a model, and nothing in the real world follows it.

Comment: It appals me that they are still teaching it 20+ years after its demise.

Comment: Connections are in the session layer, but responding to `fping` doesn't constitute 'indicating that it is accepting connections'. Only the existence of a TCP socket in LISTEN state does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Accepting connections" might be far-fetched, the system can be responding to ICMP packets, yet not be capable to do anything else.

It's layer 3, is on the same level as ARP:

http://www.sakunsharma.in/2014/07/ping-icmp-layer-3-layer-4-protocol/

[image]